# Uploaded image not saved in Web folder [symfony2.8]

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I'm trying to upload a picture, but the picture is not saved in the web folder. When i check in the database in the entity `image` i can see the name of the picture.

[image: screenshot]

AvatarType.php

```
 ->add('image', 'file', array(
                'label' => 'Image',
                'required' => false
            ))
```

PostController.php

```
public function avatarAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $entity = new Avatar();
    $form = $this->createForm(new AvatarType(), $entity);
    if ($this->get('request')->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entity->setUser($user);
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('avatar'));
        }
    }
    return $this->render('FLYBookingsBundle:Post:avatar.html.twig', array('user' => $user,
        'entity' => $entity,'form' => $form->createView()));

}
```

Avatar.php

```
<?php

namespace FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 * Avatar
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="avatar")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Avatar
{

    /**
     *
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
     * @Security("user.getId() == post.getUser()")
     */
    private $user;
    /**
     * @return User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /*
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function setUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $image
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $image;


    /**
     * @Assert\File(
     * maxSize="1M",
     * mimeTypes={"image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/gif"}
     * )
     */
    public $imageFile;

    /**
     * @var text $description
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param string $image
     */
    public function setImage($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param text $description
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return text
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }



    // Upload d'image

    public function getFullImagePath()
    {
        return null === $this->image ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().$this->image;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded documents should be saved
        return $this->getTmpUploadRootDir().$this->getId()."/";
    }

    protected function getTmpUploadRootDir()
    {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded documents should be saved
        return __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/uploads/';
    }


    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUploadImage()
    {
        if (null !== $this->imageFile) {
            $this->image = 'image.' .$this->imageFile->guessExtension();
        }
    }


    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function uploadImage()
    {
        if (null === $this->imageFile) {
            return;
        }

        if(!is_dir($this->getUploadRootDir())){
            mkdir($this->getUploadRootDir());
        }

        $this->imageFile->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->image);

        unset($this->imageFile);
    }



    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeImage()
    {
        unlink($this->getFullImagePath());
        rmdir($this->getUploadRootDir());
    }
}
```

**ADD:**

edit_profile.html.twig

```
<img src="{{ asset( 'uploads/brochures/' ~ entity.brochure) }}" />
```

User.php

```
   /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please, upload the product brochure as a PDF file.")
     * @Assert\File(
     *     maxSize="3M",
     *     mimeTypes={"image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg"}
     * )
     */
    private $brochure;

    public function getBrochure()
    {
        return $this->brochure;
    }

    public function setBrochure($brochure)
    {
        $this->brochure = $brochure;

        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        if (null !== $this->brochure) {
            // do whatever you want to generate a unique name
            $this->path = uniqid().'.'.$this->brochure->guessExtension();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        if (null === $this->brochure) {
            return;
        }

        $this->brochure->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->brochure);
        $this->brochure = null;
    }
```

service.yml

```
application.brochure_uploader:
       class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Controller\FileUploader
       arguments: [ '%brochures_directory%' ]

application.doctrine_brochure_listener:
       class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\EventListener\BrochureUploadListener
       arguments: [ '@application.brochure_uploader' ]
       tags:
         - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
         - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }
```

BrochureUploadListener.php

```
class BrochureUploadListener
{
    private $uploader;

    public function __construct(FileUploader $uploader)
    {
        $this->uploader = $uploader;
    }

    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        $this->uploadFile($entity);
    }

    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        $this->uploadFile($entity);
    }

    private function uploadFile($entity)
    {
        // upload only works for Product entities
        if (!$entity instanceof User) {
            return;
        }

        $file = $entity->getBrochure();

        // only upload new files
        if (!$file instanceof UploadedFile) {
            return;
        }

        $fileName = $this->uploader->upload($file);
        $entity->setBrochure($fileName);
    }
}
```

FileUploader.php

```
class FileUploader
{
    private $targetDir;

    public function __construct($targetDir)
    {
        $this->targetDir = $targetDir;
    }

    public function upload(UploadedFile $file)
    {
        $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();

        $file->move($this->targetDir, $fileName);

        return $fileName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why have you moved so much logic to your entity? I think the better way would be to handle upload and move to the right directory in the service or controller. Please take a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html . You can see how it's easy to play with files from the examples and you should use only wrappers for handling file uploads.

Comment: Sorry for the late response! I have tried with the example on the link you gave. When i uploaded the picture the name of the picture is saved in the database and the picture is moved the the web directory. But i have 2 problems . 1) if the user edit the profile and sumbit the form, the picture name will be deleted in the entity User, but the picture will remain in the web directory.

Comment: @sanis   2) when i'm trying to display the picture, the picture doesn't show up, if i inspect the element the link look like this : /symfony/web/uploads/brochures/ but normally it should be like this:/symfony/web/uploads/brochures/test.jpeg

Comment: Please still need help!